# How to create a toggleout or close a div?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, toggle, hide

I'm looking to toggle in an out of the content div. I can show it but I cannot figure out how to hide it again and I'm completely new to using JS and JQ.

Here is my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Thelawman/3f9Le/

```
<div class="action" data-content="#content1">
            About
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="content1">
        Here is my blurb...An amazing blurb<br>
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah<br>
        TBlah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blahy<br>
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        </div>

$("div.action").click (function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.data('content');
        $('div.action').not($this).each(function(){
           var $other = $(this);
           var otherTarget = $other.data('content');
           $(otherTarget).hide();        
        });

        $(target).fadeIn({height: "toggle"}, 1000);

    });
```

If someone has a cleaner code or a better method than mine I'm all ears.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You want to hide and show contents on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok use the code

```
$("div.action").click (function(){
        $("#content1").fadeToggle();
    });
```

Working fiddle [FIDDLE][1]   [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/3f9Le/1/

Here when The DIV having class action  is clicked, you show ,content If its for first time ,else on 2nd time click hide ,Again on 3rd click show ,hide on 4th click,So sequence goes on.

Comment: Please accept ans. if it satisfies your requirement. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your Jquery.

```
$("div.action").click (function(){

if ($(".content").is(":visible")) {

    $(".content").fadeOut("slow");

}
else {

    $(".content").fadeIn("slow");

}

});
```

Comment: @PratikJoshi If toggling the element is all you need to do, then yes, I agree. However there may be some other things that you would want to be done on showing/hiding the element.

Answer (score 0):

To use `data-content` attribute use this:

```
$("div.action").click (function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.data('content');
        $(target).fadeToggle(200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3f9Le/3/